# javascript: one confusing point about prototype inheritance

Tags: inheritance, prototype

I came into one issue in my project, which is related to prototype inheritance of JS. And abstract the main issue as following:

```
var parentObj = {
    value:"parent value",
    obj: {
        obj: "parent obj value"
    }
}

var childObj = Object.create(parentObj)
```

create `parentObj` in a literal object way, and create `childObj` based on it and make it as the prototype.

And in the first case as following:

```
childObj.value ="child value"
childObj.obj = {obj:"child obj value"};
console.log(parentObj)
console.log(childObj)
```

the output is:

```
{ value: 'parent value', obj: { obj: 'parent obj value' } }
{ value: 'child value', obj: { obj: 'child obj value' } }
```

this result goes as expected.

But for the second case as following:

```
childObj.value ="child value"
childObj.obj.obj = "child obj value";
console.log(parentObj);
console.log(childObj);
```

The output is :

```
{ value: 'parent value', obj: { obj: 'child obj value' } }
{ value: 'child value' }
```

the `parentObj` was changed. This result is a little confusing for me, any help?

Comment: I think it's returning "child obj value" for child object only.
Can you please check once again? or check childObj.__proto__, it will show parentObj.

Comment: @Nitesh, I confirmed the result I posted.

Comment: Reading the `childObj.obj` property uses prototype inheritance and obtains `parent.obj`. At this point, `childObj.obj` and `parentObj.obj` are references to the same object, so modifications to that object are visible by both means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `x = Object.create(y)`, then you get an object `x` with `y` as its `__proto__` property.

`__proto__` allows for property delegation in JS.

Property delegation means that when you ask an object for a property, if the object doesn't have it, the object will ask its parent (`__proto__`). And if the parent object also doesn't have it, then it will ask its parent object.

If the value is found before the chain runs out, it is returned, else `undefined` is returned.

---

In your case

```
var parentObj = {
    value:"parent value",
    obj: {
        obj: "parent obj value"
    }
}

var childObj = Object.create(parentObj)
```

`parentObj` is the `__proto__` of `childObj`

```
console.log(childObj.__proto__ === parentObj) // true
```

Also, `childObj` **does not** have its own properties named `.obj` or `.value`.
You can check this by using `Object.getOwnPropertyNames`.
This is the only way to know for sure if  a property exists on an object.

```
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(parentObj)) // ["value", "obj"]
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(childObj)) // []
```

When you do `childObj.obj.obj = ...`, you modify the property `.obj` on the object `parentObj.obj`.

In contrast, when you do `childObj.obj = ...`, you add a new property `.obj` on `childObj`.

```
childObj.obj = "child obj value"
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(childObj)) // ["obj"]
```

---

PS: If you'd like to learn more about hte topic, I recommend http://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-prototype/